# Powershell List of WebSites and the removal of sites in "Stopped" state

Tags: powershell, iis-7, iis-7.5

I'm looking for a way to remove all IIS sites in a "Stopped" state. Can someone show me a powershell script to do this?

```
Get-Website | select name,id,state
```

The above lists the websites, the ID of the site and the state what I've been unable to figure out is how to only list State=Stopped and how to use the Remove-Website based on the state=Stopped

The following command produces no output and no error;

```
Get-Website | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "Stopped"}
```

I hit the post button to soon, thanks...

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you have code to show we will gladly help you. Otherwise you are on the wrong site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you all sites with the state "Stopped":

```
Get-Website | where {$_.state -eq "Stopped" }
```

Since i dont have any websites to remove the following is untested but should work for the removal task:

```
Get-Website | where {$_.state -eq "Stopped" } | Remove-Website
```

Comment: Paul, both scripts works exactly as needed. Much appreciated sir.